# check file permission in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a simple web page using HTML and Javascript. I have fetched a file from local machine. I am able to get the details about the file like size,type etc. But i don't know how to get the file permission details without using `ActiveXObject`.

Here is my javascript part.

```
var f = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];
```

`fileToLoad` is the field id from html.
`f.type` provides file type.
But i want file permission (read,write).
How can i get it?

Comment: Curious why you'd even want that since you can't e.g. write the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

That kind of metadata isn't an intrinsic part of the file (unlike, for instance, its size) and depends on the operating systems file permissions system.

The cross-platform File API provided by browsers doesn't implement anything that would give you any of that information.

Comment: @entio — The code in the question uses the phrase "I am writing a simple web page" and mentions `document.getElementById`; it is clearly about browser-based JS.

Comment: sure it is, just thought a mention wouldn't hurt, for the sake of completness. In the end the title says 'in js' :)